# Raspberry pi GPIO pins wont switch

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, raspberry-pi

So I have an interesting problem. I have wrote a program to control the climate in a room. The program runs as a python program and has a web interface. The program works great but if I restart the pi all the GPIO pins turn on. Then I run my python program and they dont turn off untill I go to my switches page. Right when that loads all the commands turn pins on and off and the program functions correctly. After I have loaded that page once after startup it doesnt effect the program anymore and make the pin commands hang anymore.

Here is the code for that page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.png" /> </head>

<head>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Grow Hub</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .jumbotron {
                margin-bottom: 25px;
                height: 130px;
                border-bottom: 2px solid black;
            }

            .container {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <body>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div class="container">
                    <?php include 'menu.php';?>
                        <center>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <center>
                    <!-- On/Off button's picture -->
                    <?php    //this php script generate the first page in function of the gpio's status      $status = array(0,2,3,4,5,6,21,22);     $pins = array(0,2,3,4,5,6,21,22);   for ($i = 0; $i < count($status); $i++) {      $pin = $pins[$i];       //set the pin's mode to output and read them        system("gpio mode ".$pin." out");       exec ("gpio read ".$pin, $status[$i], $return );        //if off        if ($status[$i][0] == 0 ) {         echo ("<img id='button_".$pin."' src='data/img/red/red_".$pin.".png' alt='off'/><br>");         }       //if on         if ($status[$i][0] == 1 ) {         echo ("<img id='button_".$pin."' src='data/img/green/green_".$pin.".png' alt='on'/><br>");      }        }   ?>
            </div>
            <!-- javascript -->
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <div class="container"> </div>
            </center>
        </body>

    </html>
```

Here is the code for the script.js

```
//JavaScript, use pictures as buttons, sends and receives values to/from the Rpi //These are all the buttons
var button_0 = document.getElementById("button_0");
var button_2 = document.getElementById("button_2");
var button_3 = document.getElementById("button_3");
var button_4 = document.getElementById("button_4");
var button_5 = document.getElementById("button_5");
var button_6 = document.getElementById("button_6");
var button_21 = document.getElementById("button_21");
var button_22 = document.getElementById("button_22");
//this function sends and receives the pin's status
function change_pin(pin, status) { //this is the http request
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "gpio.php?pin=" + pin + "&status=" + status);
        request.send(null); //receiving information
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                return (parseInt(request.responseText));
            } //test if fail
            else if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 500) {
                alert("server error");
                return ("fail");
            } //else        
            else {
                return ("fail");
            }
        }
    } //these are all the button's events, it just calls the change_pin function and updates the page in function of the return of it.

button_0.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_0.alt === "off") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(0, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_0.alt = "on"
            button_0.src = "data/img/green/green_0.png";
            return 0;
        }
    } //if green
    if (button_0.alt === "on") {
        //use the function      
        var new_status = change_pin(0, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_0.alt = "off"
            button_0.src = "data/img/red/red_0.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_2.alt === "off") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(2, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_2.alt = "on"
            button_2.src = "data/img/green/green_2.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green  
    if (button_2.alt === "on") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(2, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_2.alt = "off"
            button_2.src = "data/img/red/red_2.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_3.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_3.alt === "off") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(3, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_3.alt = "on"
            button_3.src = "data/img/green/green_3.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green  
    if (button_3.alt === "on") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(3, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_3.alt = "off"
            button_3.src = "data/img/red/red_3.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_4.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_4.alt === "off") {
        //use the function      
        var new_status = change_pin(4, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_4.alt = "on"
            button_4.src = "data/img/green/green_4.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green 
    if (button_4.alt === "on") {
        //use the function 
        var new_status = change_pin(4, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_4.alt = "off"
            button_4.src = "data/img/red/red_4.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_5.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_5.alt === "off") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(5, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_5.alt = "on"
            button_5.src = "data/img/green/green_5.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green 
    if (button_5.alt === "on") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(5, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_5.alt = "off"
            button_5.src = "data/img/red/red_5.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_6.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_6.alt === "off") {
        //use the function      
        var new_status = change_pin(6, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_6.alt = "on"
            button_6.src = "data/img/green/green_6.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green 
    if (button_6.alt === "on") {
        //use the function      
        var new_status = change_pin(6, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_6.alt = "off"
            button_6.src = "data/img/red/red_6.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_21.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red    
    if (button_21.alt === "off") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(21, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_21.alt = "on"
            button_21.src = "data/img/green/green_21.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green 
    if (button_21.alt === "on") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(21, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_21.alt = "off"
            button_21.src = "data/img/red/red_21.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
button_22.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //if red 
    if (button_22.alt === "off") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(22, 0);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_22.alt = "on"
            button_22.src = "data/img/green/green_22.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //if green 
    if (button_22.alt === "on") {
        //use the function  
        var new_status = change_pin(22, 1);
        if (new_status !== "fail") {
            button_22.alt = "off"
            button_22.src = "data/img/red/red_22.png";
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your code so that it is NOT all on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the Raspberry Pi boots up, the default for the GPIO pins is all GPIO are in INPUT mode, GPIO 0-8 have pull-ups to 3V3 enabled, GPIO 9-27 have pull-downs to 0V enabled.

Your Javascript does not have an initialise routine which changes this as it only changes the states when the buttons are pressed.

Create a function which rune onload to set the pins to the default state you want.

Comment: The python code actually controls the GPIO pins these are just manual switches in the interface to turn them on or off. However after a reboot the python code doesnt effect the state of the pins untill I open the buttons.php page then all the commands go through at once to current and the programs functions normally.

Comment: I have tried running a script on startup but it doesnt change the state of the pins untill I open buttons.php thats when I hear the relays click on and off. Its like it stores the gpio writes then when I open the page it writes all the commands that I have previously sent before that point

Comment: Its the first block of code in the question and the second is the js that goes with it. 
Even using the terminal the GPIO pins dont respond until I have loaded that page up that page atleast 1 time after a reboot.

Comment: The Javascript code only changes the status of the buttons on the page, it does not alter the GPIO pins at all.  The PHP program is the only part which changes the status of the GPIO pins so they will only change when the php code executes, which will only happen when you load the buttons web page. You need to modify the pins in the Javascript program and not the php

Comment: Let me try to explain this in a different way. 
Say I have just booted my pi and have an led hooked up to pin 2. On startup the led is lit. Then I go to the terminal and enter: gpio write 2 0
The led still stays lit and doesnt change the state. Then if I go to 10.0.0.30/buttons.php (either on the pi or another device on the LAN) after that page is loaded just one time(this is just going to that page not using any of the buttons) the led turns off and all following gpio pin commands (from the terminal or other programs) change the state no issue.

Comment: Here is another example. If i use the terminal and write the state of the pin off followed by on followed by off nothing changes until I load that page atleast one time. The second the page loads the led would turn off then on then off. Its like something is holding back my commands until that page is run.